# Show most recent entry per group

Tags: php, mysql

Right quick question, I am coding logs for a mate, its rank logs for diffrent users. They now want it to show the last rank given to each person but there are mulituple inputs of the same username here is a print screen of the database https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr7Fv.png

So how could i do this?
I have tryed to limit it but that doesnt work i have also tryed to do multipul querys but i can not do that eather

```
<h3>General</h3>
     <h3>Lieutenant General</h3>
      <h3>Major General</h3>
      <h3>Brigadier</h3>
      <h3>Colonel</h3>
      <h3>Lieutenant Colonel</h3>
      <h3>Captain</h3>
      <h3>Lieutenant</h3>
      <h3>Second Lieutenant</h3>
      <h3>Sub-Lieutenant</h3>
      <h3>MSM</h3>
      <h3>CCO4</h3>
      <h3>CCO3</h3>
      <h3>CCO2</h3>
      <h3>CCO1</h3>
      <h3>Quatermaster Sgt</h3>
      <h3>Staff Sergeant</h3>
      <h3>Sergeant</h3>
      <h3>Specalist</h3>
      <h3>Corporal</h3>
      <h3>Lance Corporal</h3>
      <h3>Private</h3>
      <h3>Footsoldier</h3>
      <h3>SNCOC</h3>
      <h3>JNCOC</h3>
```

there is the ranks

Comment: You may want to phrase the question title a bit better btw

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT l1.*
FROM log l1 LEFT JOIN log l2
  ON l1.username = l2.username AND l1.id < l2.id
  WHERE l2.id IS NULL;
```

Try it out and let me know how it goes. Here's a quick and dirty fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4828/2